# A definite integral in terms of Meijer G-function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to find some relevant functional identities involving Meijer G-functions in order to prove

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}\mathrm{e}^{-zx}\,\mathrm{d}x
= G^{3,1}_{2,3}\left(z \middle|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,1 \\
 0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad (z>0).
$$

This equality came out of Mathematica, in whose syntax the right-hand side reads `MeijerG[{{0}, {1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, z]`.

In addition, it would be very nice to further express this Meijer G-function in terms of some simpler functions, such as hypergeometric functions (which could then be expressed as an infinite series). What I really need are *proof hints* rather than Mathematica magic, as I am not too familiar with complex analysis integration techniques.

NB: This question is related to an earlier question of mine:
[Closed form of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)-\log(a)}{x-a}e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728091/closed-form-of-int-0-infty-frac-logx-logax-ae-x-mathrmdx)
to which @Jason has given a valid answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First express the logarithm as a G-function, namely,
\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) = \large{G}_{2,2}^{1,2}\left( x \left| \begin{array}{cc} 1,1 \\ 1,0 \end{array} \right. \right).
\end{align}
Now the integral in question can be seen by the slightly more general integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-\alpha -1} \ \ln(1+t) \ e^{-st} \ dt
\end{align}
which is given by
\begin{align}
I= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} \ t^{-\alpha -1} \ \large{G}_{2,2}^{1,2}\left( t \left|
\begin{array}{cc} 1,1 \\ 1,0 \end{array} \right. \right) \ dt.
\end{align}
This last integral is seen to be the Laplace transform of the G-function and yields
\begin{align}
I &= s^{\alpha} \large{G}_{3,2}^{1,3}\left( \frac{1}{s} \left| \begin{array}{cc} \alpha + 1,1,1 \\ 
1,0 \end{array} \right. \right) \\
&= s^{\alpha} \large{G}_{2,3}^{3,1}\left( s \left| \begin{array}{cc} 0,1 \\ 
-\alpha, 0,0 \end{array} \right. \right) \\
&= s^{\alpha} \large{G}_{1,2}^{3,0}\left( s \left| \begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ 
-\alpha, 0 \end{array} \right. \right) \\
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-\alpha -1} \ \ln(1+t) \ e^{-st} \ dt =  s^{\alpha} \large{G}_{1,2}^{3,0}
\left( s \left| \begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ -\alpha, 0 \end{array} \right. \right).
\end{align}

It is of note that
\begin{align}
\large{G}_{1,2}^{3,0}\left( s \left| \begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ -\alpha, 0 \end{array} \right. \right) 
= \large{G}_{2,2}^{3,1}\left( s \left| \begin{array}{cc} 0,1 \\ -\alpha, 0,0 \end{array} \right. \right) 
\end{align}

Many of the transformation formulas used above can be found in the set given in:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function .