# A definite integral with with $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-1}{\theta(1+x)}}$ in terms of Meijer G-function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

I have solved the following definite Integral using Mathematica. However, as I am not familiar with Meijer G-functions, it is not trivial for me to use relevant functional identities involving Meijer G-functions in order to prove

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x)}{\theta^{\kappa} (1+x)^{\kappa+1}} \ \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{\theta(1+x)}} \ \mathrm{d}x = \Gamma\left( \kappa,\frac{1}{\theta} \right) \left( \log(1/\theta) + \log(\theta) \right) + G^{3,0}_{2,3} \left(\frac{1}{\theta} \middle|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1 \\
 0,0,\kappa \\
\end{array} \right) - \Gamma(\kappa) \left( \log(\theta)+\psi^{(0)}(\kappa) \right)
$$

with the condition that $(\Re(\kappa)>0)$

This equality came out of Mathematica, in whose syntax the right-hand side reads

```
MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, k}, {}}, 
  1/\[Theta]] + (Log[1/\[Theta]] + Log[\[Theta]])*
  Gamma[k, 1/\[Theta]] - 
    Gamma[k]*(Log[\[Theta]] + PolyGamma[0, k])
```

This question is related to

NB: This question is related to:
[A definite integral in terms of Meijer G-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795859/a-definite-integral-in-terms-of-meijer-g-function/796064)
to which @Leucippus has given an interesting answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = -1/\theta$. Show that
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^+} \frac {\ln(x + 1)} {(x + 1)^p} dx =
-\frac d {dp} \int_{\mathbb R^+} \frac {1} {(x + 1)^p} dx =
\frac 1 {(p - 1)^2}, \quad \operatorname {Re} p > 1$$
and that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^+}
 \frac {\ln(x + 1)} {(x + 1)^{\kappa + 1}} e^{\alpha/(x + 1)} dx =
\sum_{j \geq 0} \int_{\mathbb R^+}
 \frac {\ln(x + 1)} {(x + 1)^{\kappa + 1}}
 \frac {\alpha^j} {j! (x + 1)^j} dx = \\
\sum_{j \geq 0} \frac {\alpha^j} {j! (\kappa + j)^2} =
\kappa^{-2} \hspace {1px} {_2 F_2}(\kappa, \kappa; \kappa + 1, \kappa + 1; \alpha)$$
(the last step is optional). Then apply the residue theorem to the integral representation of the G-function:
$$\operatorname* {Res}_{s = 0}
 \frac {\Gamma^2(s) \Gamma(\kappa + s)} {\Gamma^2(1 + s)} (-\alpha)^{-s} =
\Gamma(\kappa) (\psi(\kappa) - \ln(-\alpha)), \\
\operatorname* {Res}_{s = -\kappa - j}
 \frac {\Gamma^2(s) \Gamma(\kappa + s)} {\Gamma^2(1 + s)} (-\alpha)^{-s} =
\frac {(-\alpha)^\kappa \alpha^j} {j! (\kappa + j)^2},
\quad j \in \mathbb N^0.$$
If we're taking the principal branches of $z^p$ and $\ln z$, then $\ln \theta + \ln(1/\theta) = 0$  and $\theta^p (1/\theta)^p = 1$ for $\theta \not \in (-\infty, 0]$, so the two formulas match for those values of $\theta$.

Comment: thank you so much. You really gave me a good insight. However, when I made a numerical comparison between the Mathematica's answer and your solution, These values did not match. 

I am wonder because the mathematical function has the following parameter $\theta^\kappa$ in the denominator part.

Comment: Which values did not match? As you've noticed, my integrand doesn't have the $\theta^\kappa$ factor.

Comment: Hi @Maxim, I have double check and the numerical comparison match exactly. By causality I did not consider the $\theta^\kappa$ factor. So, I really like to thank you so much. Now the Hypergeometric Function match with the solution. Let me be sincerely with you, the matching criteria between the Hypergeometric function and the Meijer G-Function is not clear to me because my lack in this mathematical functions. Do you have any reference that could improve my understanding of the residue theorem applied to G-Function?.

Comment: For instance, see the section on Barnes' contour integral in *Special Functions: An Introduction to the Classical Functions of Mathematical Physics* by Temme. The connection between the G-function and the generalized hypergeometric function is [Slater's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G#Relationship_between_the_G-function_and_the_generalized_hypergeometric_function), but it's not needed here, we just want to establish that two infinite series are identical.