# A definite integral with with $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-1}{(1+x)}}$ in terms of Meijer G-function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to prove the following definite integral calculated in Mathematica where a Meijer G-function is considered

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x)}{(1+x)^{\kappa+1}} \ \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{(1+x)}} \ \mathrm{d}x =  G^{3,0}_{2,3} \left(1 \middle|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1 \\
 0,0,\kappa \\
\end{array} \right) - \Gamma(\kappa) \ \psi^{(0)}(\kappa)
$$

with the condition that $(\Re(\kappa)>0)$

This equality came out of Mathematica, in whose syntax the right-hand side reads

```
MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, k}, {}}, 
  1/\[Theta]] + (Log[1/\[Theta]] + Log[\[Theta]])*
  Gamma[k, 1/\[Theta]] - 
    Gamma[k]*(Log[\[Theta]] + PolyGamma[0, k])
```

This question is related to

NB: This question is a particular case of a more general one ([A definite integral with with $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-1}{\theta(1+x)}}$ in terms of Meijer G-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409570/a-definite-integral-with-with-mathrme-frac-1-theta1x-in-terms-of)) where $\theta=1$. It is also related to:
[A definite integral in terms of Meijer G-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795859/a-definite-integral-in-terms-of-meijer-g-function/796064)
to which @Leucippus has given an interesting answer

Answer (score 0):

**not an answer** of how to compute it.  But a comment.

Your integeral is, with change of variables,
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^{\kappa+1}}\;\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)\;dx
$$
But the integral starting at $0$ is much easier
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^{\kappa+1}}\;\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)\;dx
= -\psi(\kappa)\Gamma(\kappa)
$$
so the Meijer G-function is the definite integral $\int_0^1$.  Maple does this not using Meijer G-functions, but
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{x^{\kappa+1}}\;\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)\;dx
\\&=
{\frac {-{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(\kappa,\kappa;\,\kappa+1,\kappa+1;\,-1)}
\sin \left( \pi\,\kappa \right) +{\kappa}^{2}\Gamma \left( \kappa
 \right)  \left( \pi\,\cos \left( \pi\,\kappa \right) -\sin \left( \pi
\,\kappa \right) \psi \left( 1-\kappa \right)  \right) }{\sin \left( 
\pi\,\kappa \right) {\kappa}^{2}}}
\end{align}
perhaps useful at least when $\kappa$ is not an integer.