# Evaluate the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha}e^{-\beta x}\ln(1+x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

In my quest to solve this complicated integral and learning about the Meijer function, and its variations, I am trying to compute the following:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha}e^{-\beta x}\ln(1+x)\mathrm dx$$

$\alpha,\beta > 0$ are real values.

I have tried to use integration by part but it lead me to nowhere (incomplete Gamma function divided by (1+x). I also tried to transform using the Meijer function as  $\ln(1+x) =G_{2,2}^{1,2}\left(\left.\begin{array}{l|l}1,1 \\ 1,0\end{array} \right\rvert\, x\right)$ but then I got stuck in how to continue the integral. I looked into previous posts but they are incomplete. I reached books such as integrals and series with no success.

Can someone enlighten me please on how to solve this obscure thing?

PS: Is there a way to solve this in case it becomes $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha}e^{-\beta x^c}\ln(1+x)\mathrm dx$ ??

Comment: A similar problem is solved in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/796064/1231520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote
$$I(\alpha, \beta) := \int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-\beta x} \log(1 + x) \,dx.$$

A (relatively) nice expression for $I(\alpha, \beta)$ is available for the case that $\alpha$ is a nonnegative integer: Integrating by parts and then substituting $u = 1 + x$ gives
$$I(0, \beta) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\beta x} \log(1 + x) \,dx = \frac1\beta \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\beta x} \,dx}{1 + x} = \frac{e^\beta}{\beta} \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-\beta u} \,du}{u} = \frac{e^\beta}{\beta} \operatorname{E}_1(\beta) ,$$ where $\operatorname{E}_1(x) := \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \,dt$ is the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions). Now, differentiating both sides $\alpha$ times with respect to $\beta$ gives
$$
I(\alpha, \beta)
= (-1)^\alpha \frac{d^\alpha}{d\beta^\alpha} I(0, \beta)
= (-1)^\alpha \frac{d^\alpha}{d\beta^\alpha} \left(\frac{e^\beta}{\beta} \operatorname{E}_1(\beta)\right) .
$$
Direct application of the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) then gives the explicit formula
$$I(\alpha, \beta) = \left[\sum_{k = 0}^\alpha \frac{(-1)^{\alpha + k + 1} {}_\alpha P_k}{\beta^{k + 1}} \right] e^\beta \operatorname{E}_1(\beta) + \sum_{j = 1}^\alpha \sum_{k = 0}^{\alpha - j} \sum_{l = 0}^{j - 1} \frac{(-1)^{\alpha + j + k} {}_{\alpha - j} P_k \cdot {}_{j - 1} P_l}{\beta^{j + k + 2}},$$
where as usual ${}_n P_k = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$.

For example,
\begin{align*}
I(1, \beta) &= \left(\frac1{\beta^2} - \frac1\beta\right) e^\beta \operatorname{E}_1(\beta) + \frac{1}{\beta^2} \\
I(2, \beta) &= \left(\frac2{\beta^3} - \frac2{\beta^2} + \frac1\beta\right) e^\beta \operatorname{E}_1(\beta) + \left(\frac3{\beta^3} - \frac1{\beta^2}\right) .
\end{align*}

Somewhat interestingly, if we fix $\beta = 1$, so that $$I(\alpha, 1) = p_\alpha e \operatorname{E}_1(1) + q_\alpha,$$ for integers $p_\alpha, q_\alpha$, then

- $(p_\alpha) = (1, 0, 1, 2, 9, 44, \ldots)$ is the sequence of subfactorials (OEIS [A000166](https://oeis.org/A000166)), i.e., the number of derangements of $\alpha$ objects, and
- $(q_\alpha) = (0, 1, 2, 8, 36, 200, \ldots)$ appears to be (after the initial $0$) OEIS [A233744](https://oeis.org/A233744) (*Numbers $p = a(n)$ such that $p$ divided by $(n-1)!$ is equal to the average number of elements of partition sets of $n$ elements excluding sets with a singleton.*).

These facts suggest there might be a combinatorial argument for evaluating $I(\alpha, 1)$.

I don't know offhand how to produce it, but Maple gives an unwieldy formula for general $\alpha$:
\begin{multline*}I(\alpha, \beta) \\ = \frac1{\beta^{1 + \alpha}} \Bigg(\left[ (-1)^{-1-\alpha}  \pi \alpha \Gamma (\alpha, -\beta) + (-1)^{-\alpha} \pi \Gamma (1 + \alpha) - \frac{\pi e^\beta}{\beta}\right] \csc \pi \alpha \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad - \pi \Gamma (1 + \alpha) \cot \pi \alpha
+ \Psi (-\alpha) \Gamma (1 + \alpha)
- \Gamma (1 + \alpha) \log \beta \Bigg) \\
+ \frac1{\beta^\alpha} {}_2 F_2 (1, 1; 2, 1 - \alpha; \beta) \Gamma(\alpha) .\end{multline*}
Here $\Gamma(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), $\Psi$ is the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), and ${}_2 F_2$ is a [(generalized) hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Thank you for the details. As you highlighted, the simplification when we deal with an $\alpha$ integer is really interesting. Do you think there is a way to solve this for $e^{\beta x^c}$ ?

Comment: Maple returns complicated expressions involving the Meijer $G$-function for $\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-\beta x^c} \,dx$ small positive integers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. But even for $\alpha = 0$, $c = 2$ there is no apparent further simplification.

Comment: *The integral in the previous comment should be $\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-\beta x^c} \log(1 + x) \,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Laplace_transform)

$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-s x}x^\alpha G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{matrix}\boldsymbol a \\ \boldsymbol b\end{matrix}~\bigg|~zx\right)\mathrm dx=s^{\alpha-1}G^{m,n+1}_{p+1,q}\left(\begin{matrix}(\alpha,\boldsymbol a) \\ \boldsymbol b\end{matrix}~\bigg | ~\frac{z}{s}\right)$$
So in your case
$$\int_0^\infty x^\alpha \mathrm e^{-\beta x}\ln(1+x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty x^\alpha \mathrm e^{-\beta x}G^{1,2}_{2,2}\left(\begin{matrix}1,1 \\ 1,0\end{matrix}~\bigg|~x\right)\mathrm dx=\beta^{\alpha-1} ~G^{1,3}_{3,2}\left(\begin{matrix}\alpha,1,1 \\ 1,0 \end{matrix}~\bigg | ~\frac{1}{\beta}\right)$$

There is an [alternate expression](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/03/32/) for $G^{1,3}_{3,2}$, but I doubt you'll find it very useful.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this part in the Meijer explanation. Thank you for highlighting it. Any ideas on how to attack $\int_{0}^{\infty}ln(1+x) x^{\alpha} e^{- \beta x^c} dx$ ??